# Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'onCreateRadonData'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-appsync

I am trying to deploy a DynamoDB stream as a lambda function using AppSync and Serverless. The deployment goes well, without any error. But when I trigger the lambda creating a new instance in my DynamoDB table, it fails throwing this error:

```sh
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'onCreateRadonData'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'onCreateRadonData'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
        "- /var/runtime/index.js",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
        "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)",
        "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
    ]
}
```

It is strange because, usually, I see this happens when importing some modules/dependencies in a bad way. But the function mentioned in the error `onCreateRadonData` is the name of the lambda itself, and in the deployment process, it is clearly shown that the deployment of the function went well, so I do not know what is going on...

The serverless.yaml file:

```yaml
service: aws

plugins:
  - serverless-appsync-plugin
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: eu-west-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:PutItem
      Resource:
        - !GetAtt RadonDataTable.Arn
        - !Join [ '', [ !GetAtt RadonDataTable.Arn, '/*' ] ]
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - appsync:GraphQL
      Resource: 
      - !GetAtt GraphQlApi.Arn
      - !Join [ '/', [ !GetAtt GraphQlApi.Arn, 'types', 'Mutation', 'fields', 'createRadonData' ] ]

custom:
  appSync:
    name: ${self:service}
    authenticationType: AWS_IAM
    mappingTemplates:
      - dataSource: RadonData
        type: Query
        field: listRadonData
        request: Query.listRadonData.request.vtl
        response: Query.listRadonData.response.vtl
      - dataSource: None
        type: Mutation
        field: createRadonData
        request: Mutation.createRadonData.request.vtl
        response: Mutation.createRadonData.response.vtl
    schema: src/schema.graphql
    dataSources:
      - type: NONE
        name: None
      - type: AMAZON_DYNAMODB
        name: RadonData
        description: 'DynamoDB Radon Data table'
        config:
          tableName: !Ref RadonDataTable

functions:
  handleDynamoDbStream:
    maximumRetryAttempts: 1
    maximumRecordAgeInSeconds: 1
    handler: src/handlers/onCreateRadonData.handler
    environment:
      APP_SYNC_API_URL: !GetAtt GraphQlApi.GraphQLUrl
    events:
      - stream:
          type: dynamodb
          arn: !GetAtt RadonDataTable.StreamArn

resources:
  Resources:
    RadonDataTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 5
          WriteCapacityUnits: 5
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        StreamSpecification:
          StreamViewType: NEW_IMAGE
```

And the lambda function `onCreateRadonData.ts`:

```js
export const handler = (event) => {
  console.log('Hello from lambda')

  return;
}
```

NOTE: I've also tried the `exports.handler = (event) ...` way, but I throws the same error.

The code structure goes like this:

```sh
- src/handlers/onCreateRadonData.ts
- mapping-templates/files with mapping templates.vtl
- serverless.yml
- package.json
```

As You can see I have only one file named `onCreateRadonData.ts` inside the `handlers` folder in `src`. Thats all, the rest of the files are in the root directory.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong? thank You all!

Answer (score 0):

Okey guys I got it. Since I am using typescript I have to import the `serverless-typescript` plugin to convert all the ts files to js.